# "Go Home" Siri Similar Shortcuts?

Tags: iphone, siri

Are there similar shorcuts to navigating to locations that you have saved.  I noticed "Go Home" works if you have home programmed into contacts but nothing else.  School used to work not anymore.

Similar android question https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/172333/ok-google-go-to-blank

Comment: Siri in general has decent contextual and location aware search. So I've told it "go to starbucks" and using my location it will find nearby starbucks', read them off to me (i think sorted by distance), and when I say "yes" to one of them, it'll plot a course in maps. Is that along the lines of what you were referring to?

Comment: @Vitalydotn I would like to program in my own locations like my college and stuff like that.  Read the android answer for examples.

Comment: "Take me to School" seems to work.  If you have that in address.  Also you can do "Contacts anything" and then click on the directions option.

Answer (score -3):

This article has a nice list showing the voice shortcuts of Apple Maps with Siri: http://www.imore.com/how-use-siri-get-directions-maps-iphone-and-ipad

Comment: Forgive me if I missed something but your link seems to only demonstrate the same thing I posted originally.  I would like to create custom address locations.

Comment: Similar except my answer is about Siri (your question) and the other link is Android (not your question)

Comment: Either way it is not a self contained answer